# how to convert mongoDB document into python?

Tags: python, mongodb, pandas, pymongo

I have a mongoDB document which I want to convert it in pandas dataframe

```
 db.dataset2.insert(
{ 
 "user_id"    : "user_3",
 "order_id"   : "order_3",
 "order_lat " : -73.9557413,                       ## Order location
 "order_long" : 40.7720266,
 "order_time" : datetime.utcnow(),

 "dish" : [
      {
        "dish_id"          : "005" ,
        "dish_name"        : "Sandwitch",
        "dish_substitute"  : "Yes",
        "substitute_name"  : "Null",
        "dish_type"        : "Veg",               ## Binary response (Veg or Non-Veg)  
        "dish_price"       : 50,
        "dish_quantity"    : 1,
        "ratings"          : 3,
        "reviews"          : "blah blah blah",
        "home_chef_name"   : "ghyty",
        "expert_chef_name" : "abc" ,
        "coupon_applied"   : "Yes",               ## Binary response (Yes or No)
        "coupon_type"      : "Rs 20 off"
      },
      {
        "dish_id"          : "006" ,
        "dish_name"        : "Chicken Hundi",
        "dish_substitute"  : "No",
        "substitute_name"  : "Null",
        "dish_type"        : "Non-Veg",
        "dish_price"       : 125,
        "dish_quantity"    : 1,
        "ratings"          : 3,
        "reviews"          : "blah blah blah",
        "home_chef_name"   : "rtyu",
        "expert_chef_name" : "vbghy" ,
        "coupon_applied"   : "No",
        "coupon_type"      : "Null"

      }
   ],
```

}
)

when I do the following

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(db.dataset2.find()))
```

It gives me following output

```
           _id  \
  0  566148e3691db01e0cac9d82   
  1  56615926691db01e0cac9d83   
  2  56615c64691db01e0cac9d84   

                             dish                     order_id  order_lat   
0  [{u'dish_substitute': u'Yes', u'home_chef_name...  order_1  -73.955741   
1  [{u'dish_substitute': u'Yes', u'home_chef_name...  order_2  -73.955741   
2  [{u'dish_substitute': u'Yes', u'home_chef_name...  order_3  -73.955741   

    order_long       order_time          user_id  
0   40.772027   2015-12-04 08:03:47.658  user_1  
1   40.772027   2015-12-04 09:13:10.642  user_2  
2   40.772027   2015-12-04 09:27:00.497  user_3
```

Dish is json array. When I convert it into dataframe it adds dish column and it puts everything under that column. I want to convert it into dataframe for data exploration. How to do it? I want it into following format.

```
      _id                   order_id   order_lat   order_long  
0  566148e3691db01e0cac9d82  order_1  -73.955741   40.772027   
1  566148e3691db01e0cac9d82  order_1  -73.955741   40.772027   

  order_time              user_id  coupon_applied coupon_type  dish_id  
0 2015-12-04 08:03:47.658  user_1            Yes   Rs 20 off     001   
1 2015-12-04 08:03:47.658  user_1             No        Null     001   

     dish_name      dish_price  dish_quantity dish_substitute dish_type  
0   Chicken Biryani     120              1             Yes     Non-Veg   
1   Paneer Biryani      100              1             Yes       Veg   

 expert_chef_name home_chef_name ratings  reviews          substitute_name  
0        abc            xyx        4   blah blah blah            Rice  
1        abc            abc        3   blah blah blah         Paratha
```

Please help.. thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a temporary `DataFrame` from the records in `df.dish` and [join it](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#joining-on-index) back to original `df`.

Like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(db.dataset2.find()))
tf = pd.DataFrame.from_records(df.dish)
df = df.join(tf)
```

Comment: it gives me following error... `Argument 'rows' has incorrect type (expected list, got Series`  when i do `tf = pd.DataFrame.from_records(df.dish)`

Comment: @user2927983 Try `tf = pd.DataFrame.from_records(list(df.dish))`

Comment: Not working as expected.. its putting two dish attributes under 0 and 1 heading.

Comment: @user2927983 Sorry, didn't quite get that... could you give a little more detail?

Comment: dish is basically a json array,which has two embedded elements. So,when i fire your code it adds 0 & 1 as two columns and add first set of attributes under 0 and add second set of attributes under column 1